# Need Help Vb6 Xor Large Numbers

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim Key As Long
Packet = txtSend.Text
PacketLength = Len(txtSend.Text)
key = &H82381AC + PacketLength * "17"
For ix = 1 To PacketLength - 1
OneCharacter = Mid$(Packet, ix, 1)
NewCharacter = Asc(OneCharacter) Xor key And &H1F
key = key * "13" Xor &H43B
Next ix
```

The loop will run about 3 times then overflow. I guess no matter what u do xor will result in Byte,Integer or Long. CDec(Key) will not work I need a way to bypass this so i can Xor large numbers.

Comment: 114141413415 is longer than a long. But the answer would be 114141414428, when you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can only XOR integer numbers, not strings. If you want to encrypt a string using XOR, do so by applying XOR character by character to the character codes

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal s As String) As String
    Const key As String = "r5^245ADh3%^ywftGY53Gsdr245^Tsfdgw45^fGqw4%6243TefgH563&ot7y"
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Mid(s, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)) Xor Asc(Mid(key, i, 1)))
    Next i
    Return s
End Function
```

Comment: This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f(VS.71).aspx) shows how you can remove the arithmetic overflow checks.

Comment: i have them removed from my whole project under advanced compile.